# How to remove part of element for many columns?

Tags: r

I have a data as follows:

I would like to do two things

1-  change the column names automatically for as many columns as exist 
I know that I can manually set it like

```
colnames(df) <- c("sample_1", "sample_2")
```

but I want to give a name and then it automatically add a number based on order to it for all columns.

2- I remove the part of each element I don't want. I know I must use grep but I could not figure out how, if you know any way to do it, I appreciate your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lapply the appropriate `gsub` across the columns.  The `gsub` pattern matches a string of non-semicolons followed by a | followed by a string of non-semicolons followed by a | followed by a string of non-semicolons and replaces that with the portion matched in parentheses (the capture group).  Finally we convert the resulting list back to a data frame and set the names. No packages are used.

```
L <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = "[^;]+\\|([^;]+)\\|[^;]+", replacement = "\\1")
setNames(replace(df, TRUE, L), paste("sample", 1:ncol(df), sep = "_"))
```

giving:

```
        sample_1             sample_2
1         Q9Y6Y8               Q9NZT1
2         Q9Y6X4               Q5T749
3         Q9Y6W5               Q13835
4         Q9Y6V7               Q08554
5         Q9Y6U3        P67809;Q9Y2T7
6         Q9Y6M9 P42356;Q8N8J0;A4QPH2
7  Q9Y6M4;Q9HCP0               P38117
8         Q9Y6M1               P35908
9         Q9Y6I3               P19338
10 Q9Y6H1;Q5T1J5               P15924
```

**Note:** This could alternately be written like this . ix is a vector of column numbers that should be transformed.  The others are left as is.

```
ix <- seq_along(df)
df2 <- df
df2[ix] <- lapply(df[ix], gsub, pattern = "[^;]+\\|([^;]+)\\|[^;]+", replacement = "\\1")
names(df2)[ix] <- paste("sample", ix, sep = "_") # omit if names need not be set
```

Comment: that is an intelligent way to do it :-D I really appreciate it. Is it possible to add two things, one an explanation about it (if possible) and also when I don't want to change the column names and I use the first part until setNames(replace(df, TRUE, L)) I get an error like Error in setNames(replace(df, TRUE, L)) :  I already liked your answer 
  argument "nm" is missing, with no default  , do you know why ?

Comment: Have elaborated.  If you don't want to set the names then just use `replace(df, TRUE, L)`

Comment: is it also possible to apply this on only a specific column and not all? like column 2 from the data

Comment: In the version of t he code shown in the note use `ix <- 2` if you only want column 2 transformed.

Comment: I did it like this # set the row.names as first column
library(data.table)
setDT(firstdata, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
## remove the part of string in protein name that I don't want 
ix <- 1
ix <- seq_along(firstdata)
df2 <- firstdata
df2[ix] <- lapply(firstdata[ix], gsub, pattern = "[^;]+\\|([^;]+)\\|[^;]+", replacement = "\\1")  I got this error There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)  and when I look at df2, I saw some of them are done and some not

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
require(stringr)
data.frame(setNames(
           lapply(df,function(x) 
             vapply(str_extract_all(x,"(?<=sp\\|)[^\\|]*"),paste,collapse=";","")),
           paste0("sample_",seq_along(df))))

#        sample_1             sample_2
#1         Q9Y6Y8               Q9NZT1
#2         Q9Y6X4               Q5T749
#3         Q9Y6W5               Q13835
#4         Q9Y6V7               Q08554
#5         Q9Y6U3        P67809;Q9Y2T7
#6         Q9Y6M9 P42356;Q8N8J0;A4QPH2
#7  Q9Y6M4;Q9HCP0               P38117
#8         Q9Y6M1               P35908
#9         Q9Y6I3               P19338
#10 Q9Y6H1;Q5T1J5               P15924
```

Comment: that is a good solution but not complete. please look at the row 7 for example, two parts should be separated with a semicolon Q9Y6M4;Q9HCP0 but your command put everything together.

Comment: that is amazing, I leaned from your comment, so I liked it. although it gave me the right answer, it needs an extra package (not bad though but harder to do :-) )

Answer (score 1):

**Parse the accession number:**

```
df$newcolumn <- sub("^[^|]+\\|([^|]+).*$", "\\1", df$Ratio.H.L.normalized)
```

**update:**

```
df2 <- apply(df,2,function(col){ 
    return(gsub("sp\\||\\|[^|_;]+_[^|;]+", "", col, perl=TRUE)) 
})
```

- this works on ALL columns and puts multiple accessions in the output - as requested

sub substitutes some matched thing with some other thing across a vector (or whatever).  The regex:

```
^ matches start of string
[^|]+ matches one or more characters that are not a bar (sp or tr)
\\| matches the first bar
[^|]+ matches one or more characters that are not a bar (your accession)
([^|]+) the parentheses "save" the matched contents
.* matches the rest of the characters
$ matches the end of the string

\\1 retreives your "saved" match, i.e. the replacement is the accession
```

Here I wrote the values into a new column, but you could easily overwrite the column if you wish.

**Rename the columns**

```
names(df) = paste("sample", 1:length(df), sep = "_")
```

paste puts strings together into a bigger string, but it operates on vectors too.  In this case the vector is numbers from 1 to the length (column number) of your df.  It pastes "sample" onto the front of each, using underscore as the separator.

Comment: the first part is not correct , look at the output I mentioned. Your command works only on one column and not in right way. look at the row 7, I have two part but your code only parse one .

Comment: thank you for all the explanation, although it did not give me the answer, I appreciate your answer and I liked your answer